# How can I extract data from CHIRPS for a range of time?

Tags: python, variables, range, extract, netcat

I have downloaded  data from CHIRPS in a nc file.
I am trying to extract data for a specific range of time but I heven´t  could. I am using xarray tools in python.

I select the time period and run the code but I get one with the days but in the precipitation values I get "NAN".
The time period I select does have data but when I program it nothing appears.

```
import xarray as xr
import warnings; warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# In[12]:


datos= r'C:\Users\Varela\Documents\Practicas_BAHT\CHIRPS\Year\2007_025.nc'
dat = xr.open_dataset(datos)
dat


# In[13]:


dat.var


# In[14]:


dat.dims


# In[15]:


dat.coords


# In[16]:


dat.precip


# In[17]:


data_range=dat.sel(time=slice('2007-10-27','2007-10-31'))
data_range


# In[18]:


point_d=data_range.to_dataframe()
point_d.head()


# In[ ]:
```

Comment: I need to select data for a time period, in this case it is precipitation data from the CHIRPS database. I used the "Xarray" tool, however when it shows me the results in the variable values it does not show me anything, it only gives me the dates of the days covered by the time period I chose.

Comment: The value of the variable you provide is "NaN"